# How to put the equation $y'' + ky =0$ into Sturm-Liouville form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just wondering how do you put $$y'' + ky =0$$ into Sturm-Liouville form.

Reason: I am trying to determine if the equation is Sturm-Liouville on the interval $[-3,4]$.

Comment: You gotta give us more info.

Comment: I am trying to determine if the equation is  Sturm-Liouville on the interval [-3,4]. I know it is not but I dont see why

Answer (score 1):

$-\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(p(x) \dfrac{d}{dx} y\right) +q(x) y = y'' + k y$ where
$p(x) = -1$ and $q(x) = k$.

Comment: Thank you but I dont understand why it is not Sturm liouville over the interval -3,4

Comment: It is a Sturm-Liouville equation over any interval.  Maybe there's something you're not telling us?  Boundary conditions?